# Dynamic delay time in service/delay

Tags: anylogic

im modeling cinema for school project and i came across problem. When customers enters cinema at specific time then he needs to go to specified hall, i already implemented this. Now the problem, for example, when films starts at 13:00 and ends at 15:00 then my customer needs to spent time in delay for at least 2h + time that he came before start of the film, so if he came into hall at 12:50 then he needs to spent exactly 2:10h in that hall, i am using delays for this. But the problem is how to align exits of all agents at the specified time (when film ends), because not all agents are coming at exactly same time, so i wondered if this would work, i would like to create an function which would return timeEnds - time() so the specific time/delay for the specific customer and would be implemented in Delay Time parameter in Delay block.

My concern is if the dynamic delay would change delay for each agent even for those who already entered delay or the delays would be specific for each customer so not everyone would have same delay but every one would leave at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Wait` block instead. No agent will be able to exit at ever. Unless you call `myWaitBlock.freeAll()`.

So let them all gather in the block until 3pm. Have an event at that time call `myWaitBlock.freeAll()` and all agents in the block will exit it together.

See https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/wait.html#wait